# What is the name of this anime about girls that fight monsters called The Children?

Tags: story-identification, anime, animated-series

I found an image (meme) via Google Photos over 10 years ago and it was so hilarious I saved it. The meme says "Silence. I'm not a suspicious person" even though the person saying it is holding a person...literally picked up a person and she threw him over her shoulder. You can see his (legs) light brown pants in the picture.
A description of the character that says "Silence. I'm not a suspicious" person:

- is holding a weapon out towards the person they were talking to, and it looks like some sort of gun, but it's not a pistol or anything I recognize so it's probably unique to the anime.
- has green hair and is expressionless.
- has small eyebrows and their mouth has a neutral expression (it's just closed).
- has dark eye color, maybe brown, and she's got very light skin color.
- is wearing a big hat (big like a sombrero) and it sits on her head (like a witch's hat) but it's not pointy on top, it's round. The hat is black and and their outfit has black sleeves and a different color on the chest (so maybe she's wearing two layers).

At the time, I wondered what anime it was from but I never found out. I found out the name of the anime using a reverse image search on google images and I was going to add it to a watchlist and watch it and then I went to log into the anime site I use to watch anime and I closed the tab and I can't remember the name of it, even though I just found out. It was called ... idk .... aiya ma or aiii ma or aiya ma. Something that started with an A and had a - between the two words, so basically first word - ending as the formatting for the name. It wasn't a second word though it was a shortening, such as they use shortened words at the end of names like -san or other such things.

The plot was this: girls that fight monsters called The Children. I felt like that was pretty specific so I think someone could find it easily.

Answer (score 3):

“My-Otome (舞-乙HiME, Mai-Otome) is an anime series created by Sunrise, Inc. and directed by Masakazu Obara. It is a spinoff of Mai-HiME anime series and as such My-Otome takes place in an alternate universe with new main characters.

The series originally premiered on TV Tokyo from October 6, 2005 to March 30, 2006. An OVA sequel to the series, My-Otome Zwei, has been made and released in Japan, and an upcoming prequel, My-Otome 0~S.ifr~, has been announced. The series is licensed for North American distribution by Bandai Entertainment, and the first volume will be released in July. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Yjr.jpg) In English, it is being released under the title My-乙HiME: My-Otome”

[image: Miyu Greer]